# Git filter repo of a very old folder thats now a submodule

Tags: git-filter-repo, git-filter

I've attempted to git filter repo some large files from a old folder many ways. We recently deleted that folder and turned it to a submodule(with the same exact name) so I think that's what is causing them to come back. What I've tried:

1. Normal git filtering of the file and updating the commit-map, no luck.
2. Removing the submodule, and filtering the file and updating the commit-map, no luck.
3. Checking out the very old commit with this file, and trying the filter there and updating the commit-map, no luck.

Just hoping someone has tried something similar in the past and had luck, or if it's known to not be fixable.